# How to limit log file size using >>

Tags: io-redirection, limit, size

How can I limit the size of a log file written with `>>` to 200MB?

```
$ run_program >> myprogram.log
```

Comment: Do you want the program killed after 200MB? Or do you want the last 200MB with everything older in the bit bucket?

Comment: nope, the process can't stop until manually killed

Comment: decided to go for logrotate, thanks everyone for the valuable inputs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your application (ie. `run_program`) does not support limiting the size of the log file, then you can check the file size periodically in a loop with an external application or script.

You can also use [`logrotate(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to rotate your logs, it has `size` parameter which you can use for your purpose:

> With this, the log file is rotated when the specified size is reached.
>   Size may be specified in bytes (default), kilobytes (sizek), or
>   megabytes (sizem).

Comment: +1 Logfiles with repeated information can often get compressed in orders of magnitude.

Comment: Does logrotate truncate files, or simply copy or move them?  Because this will only work if the file associated with the fd is truncated.  If it is mv'd, the file will continue to grow, if it is unlink'd, it will just be held open and continue to grow until the process exits... IIRC logrotate copies, unlinks, and creates a new file, which is why one often has to send SIGHUP to dæmons when their logs have been rotated.

Comment: Note that even if it's truncated, there's a problem if the file was not opened in append mode (log files _should_ always be opened in append mode, but in my experience are often not)

Comment: Logrotate can rotate once the file has reached a certain size, daily, weekly, etc.  It can also compress, and you can use the `postscript` option to have the logrotate config send then `SIGHUP` to the program.

Answer (score 13):

If your program doesn't need to write any OTHER files that would be larger than this limit, you can inform the kernel of this limit using `ulimit`. Before you run your command, run this to setup a 200MB file size limit for all process run in your current shell session:

```
ulimit -f $((200*1024))
```

This will protect your system but it might be jaring for the program writing the file. As [eyazici suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/how-to-limit-log-file-size-using/17212#17212), consider setting up `logrotate` to prune log files once they reach a certain size or age. You can discard old data or archive it for a period of time in a series of compressed files.

Comment: this limits the size of _any_ file written by the program

Comment: True. If the program had a legitimate need to write other large files, you would need a different solution.

Answer (score 9):

You may create a new filesystem image, mount it using loop device and put the log file on that filesystem:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./200mb.img bs=1024 count=200000 # create new empty 200MB file
mkfs.ext2 200mb.img # or ext3, or whatever fits your needs
mkdir logs
sudo mount -t ext2 -o loop 200mb.img logs # only root can do '-o loop' by default
run_program >>logs/myprogram.log
```

You may also use `tmpfs` instead of a file, if you have enough memory.

Comment: Creative idea... that leaves it up to the program as to what to do when it runs out.

Answer (score 6):

You can truncate the output with `head`:

```
size=$((200*1024*1024-$(stat -c %s myprogram.log)))
run_program | head -c ${size} >> myprogram.log
```

Comment: Very creative. Just a note that this would only work to limit NEW data being written to the file, it would not take into account how large or small the file already was.

Comment: Note that it is likely that this will kill the program (with `SIGPIPE`) once it has reached the size limit, rather than discarding the data.

Comment: I was thinking similar with some `dd` magic but yeah @Random832 is right, you'll get a `SIGPIPE` as `head`/`dd`/`whatever` drops it.

Comment: What about ignoring it with a `trap '' SIGPIPE` ?

Comment: Or pipe instead to `{ head -c "$size" >> log; cat > /dev/null; }`.

Comment: Annoyingly, this causes the first few lines of my program to output to the console: `x.sh &> file.log` vs `x.sh | head -c 1000 &> file.log`

Comment: I worked it out, I'm using `&>` so I need to use `|&` because `|` only redirects stdout by default

Answer (score 6):

In package `apache2-utils` is present utility called `rotatelogs`, it may be helpful for you.

Synopsis:

rotatelogs [ -l ] [ -L *linkname* ] [ -p *program* ] [ -f ] [ -t ] [ -v ] [ -e ] [ -c ] [ -n *number-of-files* ] logfile *rotationtime*|*filesize*(B|K|M|G) [ *offset* ]

Example:

```
your_program | rotatelogs -n 5 /var/log/logfile 1M
```

Full manual you may read on [this link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html).

Comment: The link is nonexistent.

Answer (score 6):

I'm certain the original poster has found a solution.  Here's another one for others that may read this thread...

Curtail limits the size of a program's output and preserves the last 200MB of output with the following command:

```
$ run_program | curtail -s 200M myprogram.log
```

#### References

- https://github.com/Comcast/Infinite-File-Curtailer

**NOTE:** I'm the maintainer of the above repo.  Just sharing the solution...

Comment: I love the idea of curtail. I'm not as familiar with C, so it's there a chance to provide a binary for it? or at least detailed instructions on how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is text, I would write a script in your favorite language and pipe it to that. Have it handle the file I/O (or keep it all in memory and then dump it on `SIGHUP` or similar). For that, instead of 200MB I would think of a 'reasonable' number of lines to keep track of.

Comment: Keeping 200MB of log data in memory for no other reason than to be able to truncate it isn't a very good use of system resources. Nor is doing a line count on a big log file. I would recommend using tools built for this like `syslog` and `logrotate`.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should do the job.

```
LOG_SIZE=500000
NUM_SEGM=2
while getopts "s:n:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    s)
      LOG_SIZE=$OPTARG
      ;;
    n)
      NUM_SEGM=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
if [ $# == 0 -o -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "missing output file argument"
    exit 1
fi
OUT_FILE=$1
shift
NUM=1
while :; do
    dd bs=10 count=$(($LOG_SIZE/10)) >> $OUT_FILE 2>/dev/null
    SZ=`stat -c%s $OUT_FILE`
    if [ $SZ -eq 0 ]; then
        rm $OUT_FILE
        break
    fi
    echo -e "\nLog portion finished" >> $OUT_FILE
    mv $OUT_FILE $OUT_FILE.n$NUM
    NUM=$(($NUM + 1))
    [ $NUM -gt $NUM_SEGM ] && NUM=1
done
```

It has a couple of obvious short-cuts, but overall
it does what you asked for.
It will split the log into a chunks of a limited size,
and the amount of chunks is limited too. All can be
specified via the command-line arguments. Log file is
also specified via the command line.

Note a small gotcha if you use it with the daemon
that forks into background. Using a pipe will prevent
the daemon from going to background. In this case there
is a (likely bash-specific) syntax to avoid the problem:

```
my_daemon | ( logger.sh /var/log/my_log.log <&0 & )
```

Note the `<&0`, while seemingly redundant, it won't work without this.