# Log file not growing beyond a size. Why?

Tags: linux, centos, logs, size

We have a java based web-app running on CentOS 6.0 64bit and it writes out many log files. Some of the files are rotated on daily basis using `logrotate` using the `daily`, `copytruncate` and other few options.

One such particular log file stops growing at exactly "102400000" bytes. The process continues working fine. But nothing gets written in the log then.

I did a `stat` on the file using `watch` to see if after reaching the "102400000" byte size the modified time changes, but it doesn't. Nothing happens to the file. It just stays there as it is. Other log files in the same directory continue to be written into.

The things mentioned in another StackExchange question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/how-to-limit-log-file-size-using) do not apply. I checked and rechecked if any where the mentioned ulimit option was set, but there is none any.

Doing `strace -f -p PID` showed the process to be trying to write but encountering the "File too large" and "File size limit exceeded" messages:

```
[pid  5679] write(1, "\n\n\n\n\n23-01-2013 12:00:46:921  Av"..., 128) = -1 EFBIG (File too large)
[pid  5679] --- SIGXFSZ (File size limit exceeded) @ 0 (0) ---
```

How do I find as to what is imposing this limit on the file size. Other log files in the same directory are quite large (greater than 1Gb in size) and have no issues as such.

Comment: Is this web-app home-brewn or something publicly available? (Maybe with a mailing list, documentation)

Comment: @sr_ Its home brewn, but this problem is occurring with only two particular instances of deployment. And with same file. At other installations there is no problem.

Comment: If it was a ulimit thing, the application would get killed (unless it ignores the SIGXFSZ signal). More probably it's the application itself or java that sets the limit. You could `strace -f` it to see if it is attempting to write the log file.

Comment: Presumably the application log doesn't show anything of interest?

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy The log is important. It is monitored from time to time. Once it reaches the 102400000 size, I'm moving it myself, though I can use logrotate also, but I want to know the reason first. I believe rarely does one faces such issues, and I can learn a lot from it.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Waiting for it to get to 102400000 size, will update soon then.

Comment: @GautamSomani sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant to say that I'm guessing that the application doesn't log anything relevant to this problem in the last few lines of the log before it hits 102400000 bytes?

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy No offence taken :).

No it doesn't, it keeps printing the app logs. No error at all. And no error in linux logs either.

Comment: It's not something silly like log4j being used, and the config is different for different deployments? In other words, log4j starts logging to a new file at the given size?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `strace -f` shows the process to be writing to the file BUT at the same time getting a response of "File too large"      

`[pid  5679] write(1, "\n\n\n\n\n23-01-2013 12:00:46:921  Av"..., 128) = -1 EFBIG (File too large)`
`[pid  5679] --- SIGXFSZ (File size limit exceeded) @ 0 (0) ---`

Comment: @tink No. The line for that is commented out. `#log4j.appender.H.MaxFileSize = 100KB`. And the config is almost same, the only things that we change is logging level (INFO, DEBUG, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So (from your comment), there is a `ulimit` after all (causing the `SIGXFSZ` and `EFBIG`) which explains why the size of the log can't get any larger.

You can confirm with:

```
grep 'Max file size' "/proc/$pid/limits"
```

(where `$pid` is the id of the java process meant to write to that file).

Possibly it is set by the process itself (check for `setrlimit` or `ulimit` in the strace output), It could also be set by a wrapper script that starts `java` or the java application (look for `ulimit -f 100000`).

Comment: There is a `ulimit 100000` option set in the "limits" file under "/proc". 


  But the script that is starting is using the command `ulimt 100000` only. There is no `-f` option being used. Also in the strace output, taken for 2 minutes, there is no mention of `ulimit` or `setrlimit`. 

  Do I take more strace output? Would it come eventually?

Comment: `-f` is the default option, so `ulimit 100000` is the same as `ulimit -f 100000`

Comment: Oh yeah u r right! They wanted to increase the number of open files, and they missed the `-n` option. Thanks a lot for pointing this out. :)