# How to limit screen's log file size

Tags: gnu-screen

I use run my programm under gnu-screen with enabled logging to a file (`log on` / `logfile` options in .screenrc). But after some time the log file became too big.

Is there some way to limit size of a log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want real-time control over the size of the log, you can use `logrotate` with `cron` to accomplish this.

Assuming you want to rotate `screenlog.log` in your `/home/username/` directory, you would create something like this configuration file:

`screenlog-rotate.conf`:

```
/home/username/screenlog.log {
  size 100k
}
```

then either run `logrotate /home/username/screenlog-rotate.conf` or set it up as a cron job to be run periodically. Keep in mind `logrotate` needs to be run as root by default and the configuration file (`screenlog-rotate.conf` above) needs to also be `chown`ed to root, otherwise it will complain the permissions on the configuration are wrong. Test by running `logrotate` with the `-v` flag to see if it understood what you meant.

The above configuration file is simple and **will not keep old log files**. It will just remove the file if it's over the size given, while screen still outputs its log as usual (I tested this). If you want the old logs to be kept, then you need to add `rotate N` where `N` is how many rotated logs you want to keep.

Check out `man 8 logrotate` for details on how to configure `logrotate`. Here's a related question: [How to limit log file size using >>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/how-to-limit-log-file-size-using)

`logrotate` *seems to be included by default in Arch Linux, but I'm not sure of other distributions. I'd expect at least Debian to have it installed by default and it should be easy to install using a package manager.*